# Is downloading executables from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com safe/legitimate?

Tags: python, macos, selenium, unix, selenium-chromedriver

I'm coding a python program which can open websites in the browser (in this case it's chrome).

Usually I'm using Windows 10, but I got a Mac last week. So I had to install the chromedriver for MacOS. I downloaded "chromedriver_mac64.zip" from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/.

When I unpack this zip-file I get "chromedriver" (description is "executeable unix file").

Is this serious? I've heard that unix files can be dangerous when they´re from suspicious websites etc.

I heard that this is a website from google, but the style from "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/" doesn't look like the usual google-style.

Is this serious? From which website should I get my chromedriver?

Answer (score 1):

To start with [chromedriver.storage](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) is the official repository of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871). So there is hardly any official alternative.

However, at times you may come across files as `Unix Executable File` within *Mac OS X*.

---

### Analysis

When [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) is unable to read the file's resource fork and since there's no extension on those files either, *Mac OS X* can't even guess and therefore doesn't know what type of file it is. This doesn't happen often with files with extensions most of the time, because even if a Word document lost its resource fork (type/creator codes) information, it could still use the `.doc` extension to associate the file with Word.

However, it can be either of the cases:

- The file had originated from a Windows machine (or some non-Apple operating system) and no extension was put on the file. Windows machines know nothing of reading/writing Mac-compatible resource forks.
- The files originated on a Mac, but were either transferred with a protocol or compressed with a program that ignores or strips files of that resource fork information.

There's not much you can do to get around the problem but definitely this can be brought to John's (John Chen, *Owner*, *ChromeDriver*) notice.